# TextInputLayout endIconMode attribute not found in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, drop-down-menu, xamarin.android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

In the Material Design TextLayoutinput endIconMode attribute not found how to archive below design

[image]

Thanks Advance !

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Used spinner with custom border xml

Answer (score 0):

you could add a right drawable to `TextInputEditText` like :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:id="@+id/til_password"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
  android:layout_margin="10dp">

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/tiet_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon"//add the right drawable
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: i want to set endIconMode not drawable

Comment: @logeshpalani98 i know,but as far as I can find out,no endIconMode attribute in it in Xamarin.Android,so maybe you should try other methods to archive the effect like add a drawable

Comment: Yes @Leo , Use Material Dropdown menu exposed

Answer (score 0):

Work for me

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        ...
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_close_gray_24dp"
        app:endIconMode="custom">
```

Comment: this is xamarin android not native android